# Why/how does ActiveSupport::Concern change ancestor lookup order?

Tags: ruby, activesupport-concern

Consider the following code:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Inner
end

module Outer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    include Inner
  end
end

class FirstClass
  include Outer
end

module SecondInner
end

module SecondOuter
  include SecondInner
end

class SecondClass
  include SecondOuter
end
```

Why is the ancestor order different for modules included via AS::Concern vs. plain-old Ruby?

```
FirstClass.ancestors
# => [FirstClass, Inner, Outer, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]

SecondClass.ancestors
# => [SecondClass, SecondOuter, SecondInner, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 5):

`ActiveSupport::Concern` does not change the ancestors lookup order.

If you change the `module Outer` to use pure Ruby to do the same, what AS does but without AS, you'd see, that it has the same ancestors chain:

```
module Outer
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, Inner)
  end
end

SecondClass.ancestors
#=> [SecondClass, SecondOuter, SecondInner, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: My point is that syntactic sugar provided by AS has no impact on Ruby's ancestors lookup.

Comment: Okay, so why is the order different in this case?  Does it have something to do with when `append_feature` is called in each case?

Comment: @jcm this actually might very well have something to do with that since `include` [Invokes `Module.append_features` on each parameter in reverse order.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include)

Answer (score 2):

Andrey Deineko's answer provided an important basis for understanding what is going on.

What happens when modules are included in classes or other modules?  There are two things that seem relevant:

- `append_features` is called.

> When this module is included in another, Ruby calls append_features in this module, passing it the receiving module in mod. Ruby’s default implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to mod if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors. See also Module#include.

- `included` is called

> Callback invoked whenever the receiver is included in another module or class. This should be used in preference to Module.append_features if your code wants to perform some action when a module is included in another.

We can't hook into `append_features` but we can define `included` in our modules.

```
module Inner
  def self.included(base)
    puts "including #{self} in #{base}"
  end
end

module Outer
  def self.included(base)
    puts "including #{self} in #{base}"
    base.send(:include, Inner)
  end
end

module SecondOuter
  include Inner
  def self.included(base)
    puts "including #{self} in #{base}"
  end
end

class FirstClass
  include Outer
end

class SecondClass
  include SecondOuter
end
```

The difference between Outer and SecondOuter is how `Inner` is used.  In `Outer`, `Inner` is *not* included but merely included in whatever other module includes `Outer`.  In `SecondOuter` however, `Inner` *is* included.

When the above code is pasted into a console the following statements are printed on the screen:

```
including Inner in SecondOuter
including Outer in FirstClass
including Inner in FirstClass
including SecondOuter in SecondClass
```

The first and fourth statements explain the order of `SecondClass`'s ancestors.  `Inner` is an ancestor of `SecondOuter` which in turn is an ancestor of `SecondClass`.  Thus we have

```
SecondOuter.ancestors
=> [SecondOuter, Inner]

SecondClass.ancestors
=> [SecondClass, SecondOuter, Inner, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The third and fourth statements show why outer and inner module order are reversed for `FirstClass`'s ancestors:

Firstly, `Inner` is **not** an ancestor of `Outer`.

Secondly, `Outer` is included in `FirstClass` before `Inner` is, but **`Inner.included` resolves before `Outer.included` does**.  That results in

```
Outer.ancestors
=> [Outer]

FirstClass.ancestors
=> [FirstClass, Inner, Outer, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When we extend AS::Concern and put an `include SomeModule` statement in an `included do` block, we are effectively including `SomeModule` similar to how `Outer` does it above.

[Ruby 2.3.1 Module docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-included_modules)

[ActiveSupport::Concern `included`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L124)